# Maven profiles change groupId

Tags: maven, dynamic, group

We have three profiles and each one needs to set name and groupId for our clients, but my solution shows warnings in Jenkins compilation and haven't transitive dependencys. A part of my pom:

```
<artifactId>persistenceLib-${proyecto.nombre}</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<groupId>${proyecto.groupId}</groupId>

<dependencies>...</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>client1</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <properties>
            <proyecto.nombre>Client1Lib</proyecto.nombre>
            <proyecto.groupId>com.Client1.product</proyecto.groupId>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>client2</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault></activation>
        <properties>
            <proyecto.nombre>Client2Lib</proyecto.nombre>
            <proyecto.groupId>com.Client2.product</proyecto.groupId>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>client3</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault></activation>
        <properties>
            <proyecto.nombre>Client3Lib</proyecto.nombre>
            <proyecto.groupId>com.Client3.product</proyecto.groupId>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

¿What is the correct way for a dynamic IDs?

Comment: You are probably better off by defining different modules for the clients in a multi-module project. These profiles are unlikely to work.

Comment: As already mentioned that will cause much problems... also the groupId contains uppercase parts. A groupid should in general lower case.. I also would strongly suggest to use a multi module setup for such things.. That will make things easier and you can do releases in one go which is not possible with your setup. Apart from that can you elaborate more why you are doing that and what exactly the reason is..?

Comment: This is an existing solution that always generates the same groupId for different clients, and in this case I need to generate different groupId for different clients' requirements.

Comment: @Corporativo You probably need to rewrite your project to multi-module to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, there is no option to rewrite, I'm trying to reuse this solution.